# how to split the elements from csv file

Tags: java, csv, hashmap

if I have the following CSV file

[image]

how can I split the item name and the quantity and ignore the shop name, in a hashmap list?

This is what I have done so far:

```
public class ListRead {

    HashMap<String, Integer> csvList = new HashMap<>();

    public void loadManifest() throws IOException {

        FileReader ListCSV = new FileReader("list.csv");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(ListCSV);

        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;

            String[] listElement = line.split(",");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listElement));

            // add to csvList

        }


    }

}
```

The output when I print listElement:

```
[>Shop A]

[shirt, 325]

[jeans, 475]

[>Shop B]

[car, 2]

[phone, 120]

[charger, 250]
```

Comment: Desired output ?? And please don't paste screenshots while posting

Comment: Do you need the list for both stores? A & B?

Comment: Do you wish to retain state regarding from which shop each item came?

Comment: I want the item name and the quantity stored in Hashmap<String, Integer> respectively. Ignoring the shop name

Comment: will the file always be having '>' with the shop name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ignore the shop name, then a simple parser will do:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
String line;
String currentShop = null;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (!line.matches(">.*,")) {
        String[] listElement = line.split(",");
        map.put(listElement[0], Integer.parseInt(listElement[1]));
    }
}
```

The logic here is that if we encounter a shop line, indicated by `>` followed by a shop name and comma, then we don't try to parse that line into the map.  Also, I assume that the separator for the data lines is really just commas, and no whitespace.  If you expect whitespace, then you could split on something like `\s*,\s*` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've mentioned parses the line correctly. All you have to do now is insert those items into the created hashmap.

```
if(line.charAt(0)!='>')
{
    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(listElement[1].trim());
    String item = listElement[0].trim();
    csvList.put( item , quantity); 
}
```

Also, you might want to add another Map to store the shop names if required. The above code just ignores the shop information.